# Inverting effect of resistance in an RC circuit

Tags: resistors, oscillator, resistance

I have a question on basic electronics. I'm looking at a very simple CMOS RC Circuit around a Schmitt Inverter which creates square waves. Something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR6dun.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the frequency of the square waves is a function of the value 1/(R1*C1). Hence the frequency is inversely related to the value of the resistance. High resistance = lower frequency

Is there any configuration of such an RC circuit where the relation is direct instead of inverse? Higher resistance = higher frequency? I was thinking along the lines of having a second resistance and getting to the ration of R1/(R2*C), but I can't figure out the circuit.

My use case for this is when R1 is replaced with a LDR. LDRs increase in resistance when light level goes down, but I would like the square wave frequency to increase instead when the light level goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a 555 timer circuit that uses a constant current source to charge the voltage up on the charge capacitor. The constant current source requires normally 3 resistors to set the current and one of these resistors, when increased will linearly (to a point) create greater current as its value increases. A greater constant current (higher resistance) means the capacitor charges more quickly hence, F is proportional to R.

[image]
<sub>(source: [next.gr](http://www.next.gr/uploads/64/555-IC-Linear-Ramp-Sawtooth-Generator-Oscillator.gif))</sub>

Note that increasing R1 causes the charging current to be greater thus increasing the speed at which C1 charges and hence frequency rises. Circuit taken from [here](http://www.next.gr/other-circuits/555-lm555-ne555-timer-circuits/index4.html)

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Unfortunately this is a design that's based around and RC Inverter design and I can't change the chip at this point of time.

Comment: @notthetup then you are probably out of luck unless you are prepared to add an extra transistor to shunt-discharge the cap when the schmitt trigger output rises high but then you are basically constructing a 555 timer in hardware.

Comment: @notthetup: What **can** you change?

Comment: I can add/remove passives, and maybe transistors. I am able to rewire the inverter as well. I just need to stick with the inverter.